# Jquery - Replace except inside certain div container

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function will replace certain part of the text

```
function q(text) {
    text = text.replace(/\[quote=?(.*?)\]/gi,"<div class=\"rq\"><p> $1</p><span>")
    text = text.replace(/\[\/quote\]/gi,"</span></div>");
    return text;
}
```

I'm looking for avoid the replacement of the [quote=(.*)] and [/quote] if those will be inside a certain class div (class=haha AVOID)

Example :

```
<div class="full"> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed doeiusmod  
[quote=ok]I should be replace[/quote] Lorem ipsum
dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod  
<div class="haha"> [quote=no]I shall not be replace[/quote]
bblablablablablabla
</div> 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
blablabla (other [quote] inside or not inside a div=haha may follow...)
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to put a mask for the content of your *class="haha"* div. After the masking the real quote replacement happens. At the end I have unmasked it again.

Lets check my version of it. I have put the entire HTML in a Javascript variable. I also have modified your function a bit to make it work.

```
var text = '<div class="full">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed doeiusmod[quote=ok]I should be replace[/quote] Lorem ipsumdolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<div class="hahaa"> [quote=no]I shall not be replace[/quote]bblablablablablabla</div>Lorem ipsum dolor<div class="haha"> [quote=no]I shall not be replace[/quote]bbla</div>it amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmodblablabla (other [quote] inside or not inside a div=haha may follow...)...</div>';

var resultText = q(text);
console.log(resultText);

function q(text) {
    var matches = text.match(/<div class="haha">([^<]*)<\/div>/gi);
    text = text.replace(/<div class="haha">([^<]*)<\/div>/gi, "#######");
    text = text.replace(/\[quote=?(.*?)\]/gi,"<div class=\"rq\"><p> $1</p><span>");
    text = text.replace(/\[quote=?(.*?)\]/gi,"<div class=\"rq\"><p> $1</p><span>");
    text = text.replace(/\[\/quote\]/gi,"</span></div>");

    for(i in matches){
      text = text.replace(/#######/i, matches[i]);
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so I tried, it come up on differents browser with displaying bugs, If I do not mistake, this is a browser hack ? I like it but can't be used on the code that I made (it's not standard at all and the text contain lot of bbcode / html tags / text...). It still good way for small purpose so I give +1. My solution for now is to parse [ruote instead in php and I added this line on my js function 

output = output.replace(/\[([\/])?ruote/gi,"[$1quote");

My solution isn't great but do not cost any problem with the standard. Looking for better :)